# Run Program with intellij IDEA,But there are other issues Except RESULT

Tags: java, sockets, intellij-idea, virtual-machine

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:3857', transport: 'socket' Vehicle is running now Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:3857', transport: 'socket'
```

As U can See, `Vehicle is running now` is Program's RESULT.
But what the

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:3857', transport: 'socket'?
```

---

I have VM WorkStation on my PC.
Does it bother?

and how to make that issue invisible ?

Answer (score 1):

That just means the debugger has successfully connected to that java process so that as you step through the code, apply breakpoints, etc.  All the state information for the VM will be visible and acessible in the debugger panel.

When you kill the debugger process, program terminates, etc then it will disconnect from the process right before it ends.

Comment: So, is it normal? Thanks dude

Comment: Yes, very normal.